# How to include more than one count up counter on a page

Tags: javascript

I found a nice simple bit of code to show a count up and I can easily vary the steps each count up makes. So this one counts up in 10's so 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, etc. appears on the page.

Code text is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0
    var timer; { counter = counter + 10;//increment the counter by 10
        //display the new value in the div
        document.getElementById("timer_container").innerHTML = counter;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='timer=setInterval("countUP()", 1000 );'>
    <div id="timer_container"<0>/div>
</body>
</html>
```

What beats me however is how to include the counter multiple times on a single page with each counter using a different counting amount. I'd like to be able to include a lot of counters in a table on a page with each one going up in different amounts 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

What this is for is to help my teacher wife with times tables on a big whiteboard so there would be 12 different colored areas on display featuring each times table from 1 to 12

Each colored box displayed will include:

- image - mysite.com/3timestableicon.png
- text - "3x Table"
- counter code - going up in increments of 3 and stopping after 20 steps
- text- "See - Each step is in 3's!"

I can probably figure out the table and all the different cells to make all this display correctly but I'm stuck getting more than one counter to appear on a single page at the moment so would appreciate any help on this bit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `var counter = 0` is a global variable. So if you copy n paste the script multiple times, you're sharing the same variable.

I'm not sure how much programming experience you have, but the best way to do this would be to have a counting function. Your code snippet looks like you incorrectly pasted it, but you need to have a function, say count that increments a counter and wraps it when it gets to 12 (or however high you want to go) before looping around. Remove the if statement if you don't want it to loop.

```
var k = 0;
function count() { 
  if (k == 12) k = 0;
  else k = k + 1;
  // update your divs now with the new value of k
}
```

Then you can execute that with the interval function to count every x number of millis.

```
<body onload='timer=setInterval("count()", 1000 );'>
```

Then have an update function which updates the div's with the new values. And this function would apply a multiplier to the current counter (k) value.

```
function updateDisplay(id, multiplier) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = k * multiplier;
}
```

Then you can wrap all that together for the times table of 1 to 12 by using this code in the count function to update all the div containers.

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 12; n++) { 
  updateDisplay("timer_container_" + n, n);
}
```

In your HTML you'd just add in 12 divs, each one with the id, "timer_container_1" etc.

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to put these functions together and the required divs into a HTML file.